# Nested Query with HQL or CriteriaBuilder Query

Tags: java, sql, hql, hibernate-criteria, subquery

I am trying to get the result of group by query as mentioned below

Description: I have a LogDetail table and it has created_date field and UserId field. I want to get  how many users get login per day. The created_date column is of DateTime type

```
select t, count(t) from (select substr(created_date,0,10) as t from logdetail) group by t
```

If I run inner query, it works fine, but when I run the nested query getting error... `"unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 32"`

```
    
     ID       User    LoginDate               LogoutDate  
     a000001  Arvind  06-05-17 12:15:00  06-05-17 12:13:00
     a000002  Murty   07-05-17 12:15:00  07-05-17 12:51:00
     a000003  John   07-05-17 12:15:00  07-05-17 12:42:00 
     a000004  John    07-05-17 02:27:00  07-05-17 03:25:00
     a000001  Tej     08-05-17 12:15:00  08-05-17 02:15:00
     a000001  John    08-05-17 12:15:00  08-05-17 01:55:00
```

Expected Result from the above table

```
    
     LoginDate  Frequency  
    06-05-17    01
    07-05-17    03
    08-05-17    02
```

Note: The source table has multiple entry of same user john and second point is the source date field has date-time both so first we need to get date part only from it and then apply grouping

I am looking for the solution in HQL or Criteria Builder query.

Does anyone has idea about it?

Comment: is it going to be one login per user or multiple logins for the same user and you still need a count. Also if possible, can you post the result what  you are expecting here

Comment: have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as follows

## SQL Query to get the results

```
Select trunc(LoginDate), count(ID) from logdetail group by trunc(LoginDate);
```

## HQL Query for the same will be

```
select trunc(ld.loginDate), count(ld.Id) from logDetail ld group by trunc(ld.loginDate)
```

Note: On the Hql query, map as per your column mapping on the columns

Hope this solves your problem.